# $this->db->select("DATE_FORMAT(q.added,'%d %b %y') as added") return error in sql statement

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter v2.2.0. 
I had created my own db helper.

```
db_select = $this->db->select
db_join = $this->db->join
db_where = $this->db->where
db_get = $this->db->get
db_query = $this->db->query
```

Now, here is my input:

```
    $mb_no = $this->curuser['admin_id'];

    db_select('q.question_id');
    db_select('obj.question_bm as obj_question_bm');
    db_select('obj.question_en as obj_question_en');
    db_select('st.question_bm as st_question_bm');
    db_select('st.question_en as st_question_en');
    db_select('q.format as q_format');
    db_select("DATE_FORMAT(q.added,'%d %b %y') as added");
    db_join('objectives obj','obj.question_id=q.question_id','left');
    db_join('structures st','st.question_id=q.question_id','left');
    db_where('q.admin_id',$mb_no);
```

I got an sql error at DATE_FORMAT

```
db_select("DATE_FORMAT(q.added,'%d %b %y') as added");
```

Here is the error:

```
Error Number: 1054
Unknown column '%d' in 'field list'
```

When I use db_query ($this->db->query()). It does not return error;
Here is my second sql statement using db_query:

```
db_query("SELECT `q`.`question_id`,`obj`.`question_bm` as obj_question_bm, `obj`.`question_en` as obj_question_en, `st`.`question_bm` as st_question_bm, `st`.`question_en` as st_question_en, `q`.`format` as q_format, DATE_FORMAT(q.added,'%b') as added FROM (`questions` q) LEFT JOIN `objectives` obj ON `obj`.`question_id`=`q`.`question_id` LEFT JOIN `structures` st ON `st`.`question_id`=`q`.`question_id` WHERE `q`.`admin_id` = '1'");
```

How I can use db_select to get date format using

```
DATE_FORMAT(q.added,'%d %b %y') as added
```

instead of using db_query()?

Comment: what's the error you got?

Comment: Error Number: 1054

Unknown column '%d' in 'field list'

Comment: Try to change `db_select("DATE_FORMAT(q.added,'%d %b %y') as added");` into `db_select('DATE_FORMAT(q.added,"%d %b %y") as added');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
db_select("DATE_FORMAT(q.added,'%d %b %y') as added",false);
```